# Foreach loop only returns one value, and mysqli_insert returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am new to programming and in need of help with foreach loops and getting a foreign key.
Below I am trying to send a message to multiple users.  One query inputs into the message table and the other into a recipients table.

My problems: 
My foreach loop creates only one entry in recipients table, and returns only the last user id in the array.

Using mysqli_insert_id I am unable to get the message_id (primary key from messages table).
Currently it is returning 0.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$connection = new mysqli($host_name, $host_user, $host_password, $database_name);

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$recipients = array(1000005,1000006,1000007);
$query = "INSERT INTO messages(message_content, message_subject, from_id) values('$json[message_content]', '$json[message_subject]', '$json[from_id]')";
$message_id=mysqli_insert_id($connection);

foreach($recipients as $recepient){
$sql = "INSERT INTO recipients(message_id, user_id, message_content, message_subject, from_id) values($message_id, $recepient, '$json[message_content]', '$json[message_subject]', '$json[from_id]')";}

$query_result = $connection->query($query);
$sql_result = $connection->query($sql);
```

I believe the error is in closing my loop somehow.
Thank you again!

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: For starters, what you’ve given us is a syntax error; the loop doesn’t have a closing bracket. Rather than wasting time diagnosing the problems you’ve mentioned, I’d highly recommend taking a step back and correcting a different problem that will likely solve your current problem. I’d recommend looking into pdo instead of mysqli, and read through `[this pdo tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)`

Comment: Awesome thanks. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your code using the PHP Data Object instead of MySQLi.
When generating any query from user input you should parameterise them rather than passing them directly into the string (a comment mentioned your script is vulnerable to SQL injection).

The id didn't return a value because you were fetching it before you executed the insert statement. Moving the first insert before the call to getting the last id should correct this issue.

The foreach loop only worked for one entry because you overwrote the $sql variable in the loop and then executed it after.

Moving the execution of that query into the loop will run the query each time.

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host_name . ';dbname=' . $database_name, $host_user, $host_password);
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$recipients = array(1000005,1000006,1000007);
$query = "INSERT INTO messages(message_content, message_subject, from_id) values(:content, :subject, :from_id)";
$params = [
    'content' => $json['message_content'], 
    'subject' => $json['message_subject'],
    'from_id' => $json['from_id']
];

$statement = $connection->prepare($query)->execute($params);
$message_id = $connection->lastInsertId();;

foreach ($recipients as $recepient){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO recipients(message_id, user_id, message_content, message_subject, from_id) values(:message_id, :recepient, :message_content, :message_subject, :from_id)";
    $params = [
        'message_id' => $message_id,
        'recepient' => $recepient,
        'message_content' => $json['message_content'],
        'message_subject' => $json['message_subject'],
        'from_id' => $json['from_id'],
    ];

    $sql_result = $connection->prepare($sql)->execute($params);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was not aware of this before. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Also thank you for taking the time to convert this. It was above and beyond. Cheers

Comment: We usually do not convert code to a different API. You could write parameterized prepared statements with MySQLi too.